# Navigate between pages in windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, windows

I am new to building windows 8 apps using C#.

Whenever I navigate to a page I get a pop-up saying "no apps are installed to open this type of link ms-resource". However, the app runs fine.

The code that I use to navigate to ScenarioPage from MainPage is:

```
    private void HyperlinkButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//code from MSDN
     {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(ScenarioPage));
     }
```

Can someone please help me or provide some pointers on how to remove the pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a type, you need to [pass an object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602273.aspx). From the linked MSDN page example:

```
// Navigate to object using the Navigate method
this.Navigate(new HomePage());
```

So in your case it would be

```
this.Frame.Navigate(new ScenarioPage());
```

OR, you can use the override that takes [an Uri parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602275.aspx).

```
this.Frame.Navigate(new Uri("ScenarioPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation is a namespace, not a class. Please provide a link to the Navigate method description you're trying to use.

Comment: Thanks @Roman... Solved it,actually changing from the hyperlink button to a button did it for me.